# SafeControls not added on all front-ends

Tags: 2010, deployment

On deployment in our acceptation farm, I noticed something weird happening. I deployed a wsp solution, just standard stuff. The solution contained a GAC assembly and some safecontrols. Our farm consists of a couple of front-ends and application servers. I performed the deploy Powershell script as administrator on one of the app servers.

Users reported problems I didn't see myself, so I went and checked the web.config files on the front-ends. On one instance, the web.config didn't contain the safecontrols. I checked ULS to see if something went wrong, but it listed no evident failures.

Copying a valid web.config quickly solved the problem, but left me wondering. Why wasn't this server updated and what could I do to make sure it is in the future? Anyone ever experienced something like this?